# How can I reduce three or more repetitions of some text to only two?

Tags: regex

I've got a text. I want to find out if a certain part of that text is repeated three or more times and replace that by only two repetitions.

For example, in the HTML code I'm looking at, there are 3 or more `<br />` in a row and I want to change that to just 2 `<br />` in a row.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please provide specific examples of what text you are starting with, and how you'd like to to end up looking?

Comment: abcd eeee fghklm oooooo

In this text, I want to e and o write just twice.Like this 

abcd ee fghklm oo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** As noted by Tim below, my original answer was altogether incorrect.

The correct regex for replacement would look like:

```
$s = preg_replace('/(.)\1{2,}/', '$1$1', $s);
```

It means: match any character once, then the same character (`\1`) at least twice more (`{2,}`), and replace the entire matched set with the first character, but only 2 times.

However, it might be that the above answers are probably closer to what you want.

---

For posterity, my original, incorrect regex looked like: `/(.){3,}/ig`

Comment: I could be wrong but I think this will duplicate the characters. Since `(.{3,})` would match say `aaaaa` and `$1 = aaaaa` the final output would be `aaaaaaaaaa`.

Comment: This is just plain wrong. It matches any run of three or more characters and replaces it with two instances of the last character matched. So it will transform `abcdefg` into `gg`. It seems that neither you nor whoever upvoted this actually tested this regex. If you're going for single characters (which is not what the OP needs), the regex should be `(.)\1{2,}`. Furthermore, the case-insensitive and global flags are useless here. (You need the global flag in JavaScript, not in PHP).

Comment: Tim, you are right, I was answering a question too late at night.  I'll be more careful in the future, and update the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
<?php

$s='<br /><br />  <br />';

$s=preg_replace('#(<br />\s*<br />)(?:\s*<br />)+#', "$1", $s);
print($s);

?>
```

If there are more than 2 consecutive `<br />` tags (not counting whitespace), delete all but the first two.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's possible to do this with a single regex. You probably need something like this:

```
$temp = preg_split('/<br \/>/', $input, 3);
if (count($temp) == 3) {
    $temp[2] = str_replace('<br />', '', $temp[2]);
}
$result = implode($temp, '<br />');
```

By the way: it's [not a good idea to use regular expressions for HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

If it is just `<br />` you are trying to replace and not multiple patterns then this should work:

```
$s = preg_replace('/(<br />){3,}/', '<br /><br />');
```

If you need to match several different strings then this won't work.